# Java Spark Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spark-java

How can I take a variable value from html file?
Example:
`<input type="text" value="name">`
And I'd like to take this value from this input type text to my Controller which needs it to create an object ?

I use Java Spark and thymeleaf

Comment: A value from the HTML page can reach the controller only by a user action, probably POST action. The controller is the one that updates or creates the HTML page, using Thymeleaf in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your input element in a form and add a submit button.
Once you're sure the form is sending information to the server you can access the parameter in Spark using `request.queryParams("name")`;

More on Spark's Request: http://sparkjava.com/documentation#request